# Minimum threshold in Matlab Canny edge detector

Tags: matlab, edge-detection, threshold

**Matlab Version : 7.8.0(R2009a)**

I am using Canny edge detector in Matlab to find the edges, But for my problem, I need some X amount of edges. I need more no. of edges then it is returned by setting threshold as 0. 
For example in the below image : `bw = edge(lena,'canny',0); imshow(bw)`

[image: Lena, with Highthresh = 0]
I am still getting some black area. I want to get some more edges in those regions. So, what is the minimum value of threshold, canny could take? I am already giving zero.

**Note:** Interestingly, Matlab is not giving error for negative values of Threshold. But it is still giving same edges. `[bw1 t]= edge(j(:,:,2),'canny',-7577908988800);` is giving t as `-3.0312   -7.5779`

Answer (score 0):

The [official documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/edge.html) for `edge` specifies

> `thresh` is a **two-element** `vector` in which the first element is the low threshold, and the second element is the high threshold. If you specify a `scalar` for `thresh`, this `scalar` value is used for the **high** threshold...

Try explicitly setting the lower threshold, rather than just the high threshold:

```
[bw1 t]= edge(j(:,:,2),'canny',[-inf SomethingBig])
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but Setting High threshold to large value(MAX is 1 in matlab), will give me very few or no edges. I tried setting both at -inf but I get same no. of edges as 0 :(

Comment: @MangatRai, Instead of blinding guessing valid thresholds, work off of the values of `t` that you are getting when you dont specify a threshold.